# append then delete jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

Hi am creating an image carousel. When the next button is clicked the images in the carousel move to the left. I am moving their container to the left and then removing the first image and adding it to the end and at the same time resetting the container position.

```
var $slidemove = $('#carouselslideholder').children('.carouselslide:first-child');
$('#carouselslideholder').animate({ 'left': '-' + w + 'px' }, 500,'swing', function() {
    $('#carouselslideholder').append($slidemove);
    $('#carouselslideholder').css("left", '0px');
```

`.append` seems to be moving the `$slidemove` element rather than copying it, which i wasn't expecting.

I would like to copy the image to the end, move the container, and delete the first image afterwards to prevent white space from being seen at the end of the caroursel.

Comment: Why not use CSS? Put all images just outside of border of container, container has `overflow: hidden`, when clicking left, `animate left 0`, old image `animate left -ContainerWidth`.

Comment: Isn't moving the image better than copying the image and then deleting the original?  By moving the image instead of cloning you then don't need to clone any events that may be attached too

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the idea. I think I'm too far down this road now. It works ok as long as there are enough images to more than fill the space plus an image width. I'm just being picky

Comment: @Pete - I agree (even though my answer mentions cloning). Its way better to a) move first -> last on moving right and b) vice-versa on moving left.

Comment: @user2524219 - One problem with copying is that what happens when you goto the last frame a second or a third time? Wont you need to keep track of whether you had already added the first frame?

Comment: @pete if i dont first copy the image to the end, as the container moves, a white space appears at the right hand side. I would like to fill that space with the image on the left so as it disappears from view on the left, it appears on the right. Currently the images move to the left and then after the animation completes, the new image appears

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that it is always going to be visible - ie it starts on the left, you press the slide button and it comes in from the right and is visible on the right? In which case do you really need a slider?

Comment: @pete That is a valid point. I have a situation where I have 4 images.  Only half of the last image is visible. Theoretically I don't need to scroll because you can see the image. But I would like to scroll the whole image into view if for instance only a quarter was visible. If I dont add the first image to the end, when the images move a whole image, that will leave a white space at the end

Comment: ah ok, I didn't realise you had partial visible - it's hard to picture without an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `append()` moves the element from its original position in the DOM, to where you are appending it to.

To copy, you can **[`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)** and append instead of just appending.

```
$slidemove.clone(true).appendTo('#carouselslideholder');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. When I use inspect element on google chrome I can see the new element being added, but it is not showing on screen until the animation is complete

Comment: In that case, move the above statement before the `.animate()` call. Currently it is inside the callback that gets executed on completion of the animation.

Comment: I have moved it before